# When I try to run a python web scraping code to practice more this skill I face this problem and I don't know what does it mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I was following the course instructions and steps then I wanted to practice myself but whenever I try to run the code I face this issue.

return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 10-11: character maps to

Comment: Hi, Youssef. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. Can you give us more details about your code? Put here a more complete code than you can.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is trying to encode a character that is not represented in the encoding that you are using. I'd suggest to try different encoding like utf-8, utf-16 etc. Python supports a bunch of them